# Issue on creating starting window

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to put my application on system/app. While I'm installing my app in android board, it was working fine. But, when I am trying to run the app which was put into /system/app. It is showing following error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #31: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
W/WindowManager(  591):         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
W/WindowManager(  591):         at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5459)
W/WindowManager(  591):         at android.view[ 2330.757820] mdp4_overlay_mdp_perf_upd mdp bw is changed [0] from 1 to 4
.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5594)
W/WindowManager(  591):         at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1809)
W/WindowManager(  591):         at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1721)
W/WindowManager(  591):         at android.widget.LinearLayout.ge[ 2330.775766] mdp4_overlay_mdp_perf_upd mdp bw is changed [1] from 4 to 1
nerateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:58)
W/WindowManager(  591):         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
W/WindowManager(  591):         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
W/WindowManager(  591):         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
W/WindowManager(  591):         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
W/WindowManager(  591):         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2784)
W/WindowManager(  591):         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.[ 2330.846970] mdp4_overlay_mdp_perf_upd mdp bw is changed [0] from 1 to 4
PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2844)
W/WindowManager(  591):         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1542)
W/WindowManager(  591):         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.addStartingWindow(PhoneWindowManager.java:1561)
W/WindowManager(  591):         at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:6987)
W/WindowManager(  591):         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/WindowManager(  591):         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/WindowManager(  591):         at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$WMThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:828)
D/PowerManagerService(  591): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AudioOut_3
I/ActivityManager(  591): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=peer.ir/.MainActivity u=0} from pid 805
```

But, I used layout_height in all views in my xml. I have given my xml file below for your reference. I couldn't find out what mistake have I done?

Answer (score -1):

Is still rooted the device where you try to install as System App?

If rooted, please copy your App on SD Card and after follow these ADB steps:

```
adb shell
su

cd sdcard/

mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system

cat YOURAPP.apk > /system/app/YOURAPP.apk


chmod 644 /system/app/YOURAPP.apk

reboot
```